# Decode to Case Statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to convert the below decode to Case statement in SQL. Tried multiple ways , not able to get it right.

```
select 
DECODE(SIGN(A.column - to_date(( 
              DECODE('10/01/2011',
                     '%',to_char(A.column,'mm/dd/yyyy'),'10/01/2011') ),
                     'mm/dd/yyyy')),
      -1, 0, 
      A.Amount)) 
from A
```

Comment: Please post what you tried and the issues with your code. Also, is this query working?

Answer (score 2):

```
select  case 
            when to_date(nullif(:dt,'%'),'mm/dd/yyyy') > A.column 
            then 0 
            else A.Amount 
        end

from    A
```

Comment: NULLIF makes plus one - learned a new thing!

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to handle such code is to remove it and find the original requirement.

I suspect it was such as

1) if '%' is passed return `AMOUNT`

2) if a date string is passed return `AMOUNT` if the `COLUMN` is greater or equal than the parameter

3) return `0` otherwise

This leads to following CASE statement

```
select A."COLUMN",
case when :1 = '%' then A.Amount
when  A."COLUMN" >= to_date(:2,'mm/dd/yyyy')  then A.Amount 
else 0 end as amount
from A;
```